# How to change id field in miragejs db

Tags: reactjs, mocking, web-frontend, ui-testing, miragejs

I am wondering how I could change the default, generated id column for a mirage db from 'id' to something like 'userId' as my front end expects.
Thanks!

Comment: @JoseLora Hopefully my answer solves the mystery of what my question was. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out, this can be done by extending your serializer and using the keyForAttribute function. It will look something like:

```
createServer({
  serializers:{
    user: RestSerializer.extend({
      keyForAttribute(key){
        return key === 'id' ? 'userId' : key
      },
    })
  },
  //models{...}
  // rest of createServer...
)}
```